# Rspec cookies.permanent, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, rspec

I am getting an error when I run rspec using bundle which is as follows :

`undefined method 'permanent' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00000003dd3990>`

I have following code in `SessionsHelper`

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

I am using `rvm` version :

`rvm 1.17.9 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Ruby version :

`ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to define `sign_in` i.e. function which is assigning value to `cookies.permanent` hash in `spec/support/utilities.rb`

And rather assigning value to `cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`, assign value to `cookies[:remember_token]`